# The glyphicons height not matching with select2 dropdown

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2, glyphicons

When i add select2 dropdown the glyphicons icon height was not same
[image]

This is the html code

```
 <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="user_edit">

  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 nopadding control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8 nopadding inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group field-width">

             <span class="input-group-addon" >
              <i class="fa fa-venus-mars" ></i></span>
               <select name="gender" id="gender" class="gender form-control 
     js-example-basic-single">
                    <option value="">Not Telling</option>
                    <option value="m">Male</option>
                    <option value="f">Female</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

The js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
```

The css file i add for select2

```
.glyphicon{
color:#007bcc;
 }
 .select2-selection__rendered{
 line-height: 32px!important;
 }
 [class^='select2'] {
 border-radius: 0px !important;
 }

 .select2-selection__arrow{
  height: 34px;!important;
  }
 .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single{
 background-color: #eeeeee !important;
 height: 34px!important;
 font-size: 15px;!important;
  margin-top: 0.5px!important;
 margin-left: -1px!important;

 }
```

When i zoom the page more than 100% the height same.

Comment: can you fiddle here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `margin-top: 0.5px!important;` from `.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
```

```css
.glyphicon{
color:#007bcc;
 }
 .select2-selection__rendered{
 line-height: 32px!important;
 }
 [class^='select2'] {
 border-radius: 0px !important;
 }

 .select2-selection__arrow{
  height: 34px;!important;
  }
 .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single{
 background-color: #eeeeee !important;
 height: 34px!important;
 font-size: 15px;!important;

 margin-left: -1px!important;

 }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="user_edit">
  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 nopadding control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8 nopadding inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group field-width">
             <span class="input-group-addon" >
              <i class="fa fa-venus-mars" ></i></span>
               <select name="gender" id="gender" class="gender form-control 
     js-example-basic-single">
                    <option value="">Not Telling</option>
                    <option value="m">Male</option>
                    <option value="f">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why the position of row not same when i zoom in after 150%